# Replicate and move Apple Music library to different AppleID

Tags: itunes, icloud, apple-id, apple-music

My wife and I started sharing the same Apple Music Library via a shared AppleID many, many years ago. This was way before family sharing. We'd like to have our own music libraries moving forward but we want to replicate the base library. I realize that the new library will loose music purchased via iTunes, which is fine. We're mostly focused on playlists that we've created after the Apple Music was launched. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: See https://support.apple.com/guide/music/save-a-copy-of-your-playlists-mus27cd5060f/mac

Comment: Does it answer your question? I shall for your answer wait to post my comment as one. - Thanks @mmmmmm :)